# I am not able to cover a test class

Tags: unit-test

I am not able to cover an listAccBalance in a testclass.My code is mentioned below :-

Apex Class :-

```
public class AccountBalance2Aura {
    @auraEnabled
    public static Account getAccBalance(){
        List<User> currentUserList = [SELECT id,contact.account.Investor_Account_Balance__c 
                                      FROM User
                                      WHERE id = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
                                      AND contact.account.Investor_Account_Balance__c != NULL];

        if(currentUserList.size()>0){                         
            List<Account> listAccBalance = [SELECT Id,Realized_Gain__c,Unrealized_Gain__c, 
                                                                Investor_Account_Balance__r.Committed_Fund_Balance__c,
                                                                Investor_Account_Balance__r.Outstanding_Fund_Balance__c,
                                                      Investor_Account_Balance__r.Total_Funds_Deposited__c
                                                                FROM Account
                                                                WHERE Investor_Account_Balance__c =:currentUserList[0].contact.account.Investor_Account_Balance__c ];
            if(listAccBalance.size()>0)
                return listAccBalance[0];
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Test Class :-

```
@istest
public class AccountBalance2AuraTest {
    public static Testmethod void mytest(){
         Investor_Account_Balance__c iab=new Investor_Account_Balance__c();
        //iab.CurrencyIsoCode='SGD-Singapore Dollar';
        iab.Committed_Fund_Balance__c=1235;
        iab.Outstanding_Fund_Balance__c=4563;
        iab.Total_Funds_Deposited__c=65412;
        insert iab;
         Account Acc = new Account();
        Acc.Name='Test';
        Acc.Investor_Account_Balance__c=iab.id;
        insert Acc;

        Contact con=new contact();
        con.NRIC_Passport__c='testp';
        con.LastName='test1';
        con.AccountID=Acc.id;
        insert con;
        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Customer Community Investor'];
        user  u = new User(alias = 'standt', email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                           emailencodingkey='UTF-8', 
                           lastname='Testing', 
                           languagelocalekey='en_US', 
                           localesidkey='en_US', 
                           profileid = p.Id, 
                           contactid=con.id,
                           timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                           username='standarduser@testorg.com');
        insert u;

        AccountBalance2Aura obj=new AccountBalance2Aura();
        AccountBalance2Aura.getAccBalance();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` whenever executing the methods that should cover your code. Also, in your where clause `Investor_Account_Balance__c =:currentUserList[0].contact.account.Investor_Account_Balance__c`, you are using a value that is supposed to be under some user's context, you need to run the whole test class under `System.runAs(myUSER)`. Please read more about these to cover your test class.

Answer (score 0):

you just use this code and run your class as System.runas(u)

```
 Profile profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator [Actual]' LIMIT 1];

  User u = new User(
           ProfileId = profileId.Id,
           LastName = 'last',
           Email = 'puser000@amamama.com',
           Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
           CompanyName = 'TEST',
           Title = 'title',
           Alias = 'alias',
           TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
           EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
           LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
           LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
      );
```

hope this will help you!!